# Set condition for s3 file imported to pyspark

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am new PySpark and AWS EMR.

For Pyspark.py script, its simple as below:

I would like to check the s3 file contents load to start with `123xxxx`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: wordcount  ", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
    text_file = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    if text_file.startswith('123'):
        counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
        counts.saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
        sc.stop()
    else:
        exit(-1)
```

When I run steps in AWS emr :

```
s3a://sparkpy/output/a/a.txt s3a://sparkpy/output/a
```

But it got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I count string and compare:

```
rdd = text_file.filter(lambda x: "gfg" in x)
    if rdd.count() > 0:
```